# WCF test client and proxy settings

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcftestclient

I am trying to run WCFTestClient and generate configuration for service. Unfortunately I am behind proxy and I receive `407: Proxy Authentication Required`

How can I run WCFTestClient to connect beind proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it will work or not. You can try modifying the WCFTestClient.exe.config (You can find this file - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE depends on your VS installation) and add the following lines

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

Please make sure you have a backup of the config file. Hope it works.

Comment: I did it also in `svcutil.exe`

Comment: svcutil.exe also required?

Comment: I must did something strange. It is enough what you wrote.